# How to include fadein effect to .html() method in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am changing a div's inner html by jquery's .html() method

```
$("#model_desc_inner").html(current_text).fadeIn("slow");
```

I want to apply some effect on changing of new text. For this purpose I included `.fadeIn("slow")` method at the end.

But it is not including fadeIn effect on changing of new text.

Please give me some solution.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
$("#model_desc_inner").fadeOut(function() {
   $(this).html(current_text).fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The method name is `fadeIn` not `fadein`. JavaScript is case-sensitive! Also if the `"#model_desc_inner"` element is already visible, `fadeIn` effectively doesn't do anything. You should at first `.hide()` the element.

```
$("#model_desc_inner").hide().html(current_text).fadeIn("slow");
```

Comment: Thank you that was also a syntax error in fadein. I changed it to fadeIn. But it is still not working because the text is already visible. <br />Can you give code to first hide then fadeIn the text?

Comment: @Rashid What is that text? If it's a `textNode` you can't directly hide/show it. You should show/hide it's `parentNode` just like you are currently doing. Can you provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that in it the above code fails to do what you are trying to achieve?